# how to click on dynamically generated URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have a url coming from backend when user clicks on some button. This url contains a file. When clicked on the url, the file should get downloaded. I tried doing is by dynamically generating the anchor tag and the programmatically clicking on it using the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). The code which I have written is as follows :

```
const link = document.createElement('a'),
      event = new MouseEvent('click');

link.href = data;
link.dispatchEvent(event);
```

But this redirects me to the url instead of downloading it. Surprisingly, a few days ago, this code was working fine. What is the best way to do it.

1. Which should be browser independent
2. I can't use jquery, I'm writing this in react and want to write it in javascript.

**[EDIT]** : 
if this question is duplicate or wrongly asked, please comment. I couldn't find this specific question and most answers used jquery.

Comment: link.download=true; you can also add a serverside header to the file to force its download...

Comment: since you mention that this code was working previously, one thing it could change is the response from server, e.g. not returning the file as attachment

Comment: @derloopkat, earlier the browser was allowing me to open the file (or download) from the new tab if I pasted that on my browser tab but now it is not allowing me to open, may be the file is protected or something, but I saw it somewhere that we can download such files

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
var url = data; 
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.href = url;
element.setAttribute('download', name);
element.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
document.body.appendChild(element); //Append the element to work in firefox
element.click();
```

Comment: Will I need to removeChild after I have clicked?

Comment: I used this solution and React gave me this warning in console : Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `clientY` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). 
I know about the pooling of event but I really didn't get why it gives me this warning on click() event